# C++ Multi threaded Program got crashed with BUS error

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, coredump, bus-error

My Project got crashed after 5 days of testing , when I analyze the dump file its showing as `BUS` Error

Here the below chunk of code i got from the `backtrace`

```
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.

#0  0x0000000000000531 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 902)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000531 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000041a294 in CUtilsTimer::forgetTimer() ()
#2  0x0000000000415160 in CEMPLinkMonitor::monitor_ethernet_link_status() ()
#3  0x0000000000413fc8 in CEMPTransport::recvEMPData(Emp_Packet*) ()
#4  0x000000000041313c in CEMPRxTransport::run() ()
#5  0x00000000004190a8 in CUtilsThread::runLoop(void*) ()
#6  0x0000007fac289fb8 in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000007fa74bdc98 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

I tried to find the root cause but not able get any clue to crack , Please help

Comment: I think no one can help you here. Is there any possibility to reproduce the error? You could look at record & replay debugging

Comment: Bugs like this can be very tricky to locate. Start with looking for data that you're sharing between threads without proper synchronization or lifetime management.

Comment: If your platform supports the valgrind family, I would give them a chance. But be aware that they currently have no atomic<> support! If your process synchronization is based on mutex and co, it will help a lot.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, No I am not able to reproduce

Comment: Apart from other suggestions, you can also add a debug flag (-g in g++) to your compiler

Comment: 0x531 is a very suspicious looking address, since it is within the range of the unmapped page for null (unless you have a machine with a 1k page size).  That likely means that forgetTimer is invoking a function pointer / virtual function which has either not been initialized or has been over-written.   Try valgrind, it might give you more info.